# dojo not found from popmenu

Tags: xpages

I am getting an error:

Script interpreter error, line=3, col=28: [ReferenceError] 'dojo' not found

```
 1: viewScope.ppChoice=context.getSubmittedValue();
 2: dBar.info("I am here");
 3: var fileUploadPanel = dojo.byId("#{id:fileUploadPanel}");
 4: var fileUpload1 = dojo.byId("#{id:fileUpload1}");
 5: var butImport = dojo.byId("#{id:butImport}");
 6: dojo.style(fileUploadPanel, "display", "block");
 7: dojo.window.scrollIntoView(butImport);
 8: fileUpload1.focus();
```

on a onItemClick event of an extension library popup menu.  This same code run just fine in a normal button event.   I do plan to not use the popupmenu now but I am still curious as to why I get this error from the onItemClick event.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onItemClick event of xe:dropDownButton expects server-side JS. You are mixing SSJS with dojo which is client-side JS.